# Kitten licks genitals ( a lot). (Serious question). Can I get him to stop it

Tags: cats, behavior

I took my kitten for shots. He is 3 months old. He licks his genital area so much it hurts him sometimes to urinate. My Vet says he has never seen this and he has been a Vet for 25 years. Any suggestions on how to help the little fella stop. It's pretty obsessive. Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest a cone until the site has a chance to heal, then see if the problem persists after the area is no longer sore.

Answer (score 4):

The kitten may have a medical problem or birth defect which is causing him discomfort in that area. When a cat feels itchiness or pain, they will respond by licking. One possibility is a hernia. Another possibility is that he is having an allergic reaction to the shots.